# Identifying C 11 keywords in Strings (string.at() issues)

Tags: c++, string, search, c++11

I have been successful in searching for c++11 keywords in code snippets provided by the professor in the main function. Although when printed keywords are printed if they are included within other words like do is printed when donuts exist when the string snippet. So I created two if statements which identify the next char in a string and whether or not it is a space character and if it is it proceeds to print it. But i am having an issue in the x.at() statement which compiles but does not run. Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

```
// C++11 Keyword Search Program

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;
typedef vector<string> string_vector;

// return the C++11 keywords that appear in the code snippet
string_vector find_keywords(const string snippet)
{
  const string x=snippet;
  int len=x.length();
  int back=x.back();
  int last_char, first_char;
  vector<string> answer;
  string keywords[]= {"alignas", "alignof", "and", "and_eq", "asm", "auto", "bitand", 
      "bitor", "bool", "break", "case", "catch", "char", "char16_t", "char32_t", "class", "compl", "const", "constexpr",
      "const_cast", "continue", "decltype", "default", "delete", "do", "double", "dynamic_cast", "else", "enum", 
      "explicit", "export", "extern", "false", "float", "for","friend", "goto", "if", "inline", "int", "long", "mutable",
      "namespace", "new", "noexcept", "not", "not_eq", "nullptr", "operator", "or", "or_eq", "private", "protected public", 
      "register", "reinterpret_cast","return","short","signed","sizeof","static","static_assert","static_cast","struct",
      "switch", "template", "this","thread_local","throw","true","try","typedef","typeid","typename","union","unsigned",
      "using","virtual","void", "volatile","wchar_t","while","xor","xor_eq"};



     for(int i=0;i<83;++i)
  {
    string test=keywords[i];
    size_t found = x.find(test);
    unsigned int testsize=test.size();
    int test1=0,test2=0;

    if(found!=string::npos)
    {
        char a=x.at(found-1);
        char b=x.at(found+testsize);
        int c=isalpha(a);
        int d=isalpha(b);
        if (c>=1)
            test1=1;
        if (d>=1)
            test2=1;
    }   
    if(found!=string::npos && test1==0 &&test2==0)
        cout<<test<<" ";        
  }
return answer;
}

int main (int argc, char* const argv[])
{
  const string snips[] =
  {
    "int i = 0;",
    "i += 1;",
    "return (double) x / y;",
    "char foo(char bar);",
    "double bar(void) const",
    "garbage = fuzz + lint;"
  };

  const string_vector snippets(snips,snips + 6);

  for (auto snippet : snippets)
  {
    cout << "**Snippet**  " << snippet << endl << "**Keywords** ";
    for (auto keyword : find_keywords(snippet))
    {
      cout << ' ' << keyword;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why the hell are you using **two** `const string` instances? Heck, why are you even using `const string` instances?

Comment: Vandalizing your own post is not permitted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> last_char=found+len-1;
> char2=x.at(last_char);
> ```

As soon as `found > 0`, then `last_char >= x.length()` and your `at()` call attempts to read out of bounds.

Note also that a space is not the only possible token delimiter. One routinely writes things like `break;`, or `return;`, or `while(condition)`, or `f(int[])`, or `this->member`. All of these contain a keyword that is not surrounded by spaces.

And, a string that looks like a keyword may appear in a string literal, `"like this"`.

Comment: i used this and your space as the only token delimeter and completely reamped my code. First i inserted spaces into the front and end of the strings to avoid out of bounds headaches and checked the character before and after each instance where it found something and if that was a letter i told the program to ignore that instance where it had found it.